# 14 piece wooden cube puzzle

Tags: puzzle-identification

[image]

I bought this 14 piece wooden cube puzzle a while back, which I can’t remember the name of. I’ve been trying for a while now, and have also been searching the Internet for a solution. What type of puzzle is this, and ,secondly, what is the solution to the puzzle as a whole? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This type of puzzle is called a burr puzzle. This particular one was designed by Bill Cutler, and is called Wausau '83.
It is produced by Jerry McFarland, and available from [Bill](http://billcutlerpuzzles.com/stock/wausau83.html) himself, or from [Mr Puzzle](https://www.mrpuzzle.com.au/wausau-bill-cutler-burr.html) in Australia.

There are some blogs that review the puzzle, for example [here](https://www.puzzlemad.co.uk/2011/03/bill-cutlers-wausau-83.html) and [here](http://allardspuzzlingtimes.blogspot.com/2011/04/burr-is-burr-is-burr-or-not.html), but few solutions to be found. The only solution I came across was on [Jim Storer's site](https://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~storer/JimPuzzles/ZPAGES/zzz14PieceWausau83.html), which shows Bill Cutler's solution, as supplied by Mr. Puzzle, which is a diagram of which piece belongs where. It does not actually show what moves you need to do to get the pieces in those positions, and that can be tricky considering it takes 11 moves to take out the first piece (and conversely 11 moves to put the last piece in).

Comment: Came and saw, and thought it was a burr puzzle, then scrolled down. :) +1